# Managed package upgrade after licensing changes

Tags: apex, managed-package, licenses

We recently moved our licensing structure from side-wide licensing to per-user based licensing. We have to upgrade our old subscribers to the new licensing model.

Since it was a side wide license, individual licenses were not assigned to users. Assuming we want to give access to all the current users using the app. How do we ensure the upgrade goes smoothly without breaking anything.

- Should we get the administrator to assign licenses manually to all users before doing the upgrade?
- Or we should assign licenses programmatically in the upgrade script?

Comment: I vote upgrade script as relying on admins does not help your desire to flawlessly upgrade

Comment: Thanks. This would work in case if I want to assign it to all users. But I guess the problem would be in  differentiating between 'normal upgrades' and 'upgrades from side wide licenses' in the post install script. We do not want to assign licenses to all users when it a normal upgrade.

Comment: Versioning, deployment plan, checking version in script. Only do it in the version they need to install after you make the change

Comment: Ah, versioning. Yes that makes sense. Thanks a lot!